# how do i protect my java code in game maker extension

Tags: java

I release a new java based Game Maker Studio extension having spent many days putting it together.

Few downloads later someone decides it nice, they get your extension and the code and make their own copy/version and sell it on marketplace for much lower price. As I beleive the java code in the extensions is easily exposed.

So whats stopping people from copying and undercutting you?

I suppose you can obfuscate your code, java etc..

But thats not really hard to still copy and alter.

What else is there. I was thinking of wrapping the class into a jar file (mind you I know nothing about this) and then importing those and just referencing the functions/methods in the extensions .java file. Is this possible if so id like to know how.

Comment: Have you tried looking into how to de-compile Java code and ways to prevent someone from doing that?

Comment: they dont need to decompile the .java file. it can simply be opened by notepad and they can read the code

Comment: Why are you distributing java files if you don't want people copying your code? A jar file doesn't contain java files, it contains class files. And those would need decompiled